# How to show marker while tracking on its current location in nutiteq maps android

Tags: android, maps, polyline, nutiteq

Please provide me with some idea where I am drawing a polyline using nutiteq maps while tracking but wants to show a marker on the polyline simultaneously on its tracking.
Your kind suggestions  will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a geometry layer with Line for polyline and marker layer with a Marker. You can mutate both objects (updating mapPos) whenever you need.